# Mobile broadband is unavailable

Tags: networking, 20.04, usb-modem, modem-manager, usb-modeswitch

I've bought 4G LTE wireless (can work as mobile broadband too) USB dongle, it works fine on Windows and macOS.

[image]

But from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04 takes too much time to be detected and when detected says: "Mobile broadband unavalaible". I don't know what's the situation in Ubuntu 18.04, but I'd rather not consider install it.

Wi-Fi is still active, though I can't connect... (Even though the dongle only needs power source to work wireless)

My modem's name is Bvot LTE 4G and it supports macOS and Windows. But vendor said it'd work well on Linux too... Well, it was supposed to 'just work'.

[image]
[image]

```
$ usb_modeswitch -W -v 05c6 -p 6000 -K
Take all parameters from the command line


 * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 2.6.1 (C) Josua Dietze 2017
 * Based on libusb1/libusbx

 ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x05c6
DefaultProduct= 0x6000

StandardEject=1

Look for default devices ...
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 8087:0aa7
  found USB ID 05c8:0233
  found USB ID 05e3:0608
  found USB ID 0bda:0177
  found USB ID 05c6:f000
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 045e:07fd
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 No devices in default mode found. Nothing to do. Bye!
```

Based on lsusb the manufacture device real name is Qualcomm, Inc. Siemens SG75. I think all additional information about the model can be found [here](https://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?t=2970). Every description there works on me too...

Please, help...

Comment: Could you update your question to include the brand & model of the USB device? The output of `lsusb` may also be useful in determining compatibility and/or driver requirements.

Comment: Of all USB dongle I've tried on Linux I met with nearly similar circumstances... Why is mobile broadband support on Linux so poor (trash), when it's very basic and important thing?

Comment: Have you ever tried to reverse engineer some of these devices to make them work with Linux? My goodness, you'd think hardware manufacturers hated all of humanity sometimes. Microsoft and Apple have the marketshare, so companies approach them asking for help so their devices are supported out of the box. Few companies will approach a Linux-based company like Canonical to ensure greater compatibility across all platforms.

Comment: From explicit to implicit support to Linux... Same thing. Nothing change.

Comment: I don't know for sure if my USB dongle doesn't have Linux drivers (What I doubt)... Anyway, It has Dual mode: WiFi and Dongle. Can someone help me configure it manually? (Those types of USB Dongle exists for more than 5 years, for Christ sake... Help)

Comment: Not a USB dongle, it's a MiFi and its typical usage is via WiFi. Why are insisting in using it any other way? As long as it's working in the preferred WiFi mode it's an AP like any other, no special support (other than WiFi) is needed in the client device. Most actual USB 3G/4G/5G modems work in Ubuntu and are "plug'n'play" either in pure USB modem ("mobile broadband") mode (settings at OS) or USB Ethernet mode (settings at the device's webserver). (...)

Comment: https://jiji.com.gh/labadi/networking-products/m81-bvot-mobile-wifi-4g-lte-pocket-mifi-nkkYTEhRh5N19c3gTB6f6xrG.html Pic. #4 clearly shows the device acting as a WiFi AP, not physically connected to any of its clients. https://www.wikihow.com/Connect-to-MiFi explains how to use this devices.

Comment: I can assure it's not MiFi, it's USB Dongle (Or simply, Dongle) with dual modes... It doesn't have battery, so it needs power source...

Comment: Ubuntu messes up with WiFi when it tries to configure it as mobile broadband (another functionality) or other way around.

Comment: I uploaded the model to end misunderstandings...

Comment: I had to temporarily remove `usb-modeswitch` to work on WiFi mode... Please somebody, help! (Good thing I bought yesterday dual mode dongle...)

Comment: The dongle on Ubuntu probably works for WiFi. For it to work as mobile broadband, you will probably have to install new drivers for it.

Comment: I don't know... I was forced to reinstall `usb-modeswitch` again to submit some log report, after that I disabled. It just doesn't work well with it enabled. And USB port power suspension also occurred on ZTE USB Dongle, which came with explicit Ubuntu support.

Comment: `usb_modeswitch -W -v 05c6 -p 6000 -K` can you add this to your question? Please as text no picture.

Answer (score 0):

The modem will create /dev/sr1. Run "eject /dev/sr1".
If modem reboot, remove ModemManager app. ModemManager sends "At+CFUN=2" command. This command crashes the modem. Without ModemManager, use wvdial to make a ppp conection.